# NOW() within IF Formula stopped working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

One of the formulas in my Excel tracker stopped working yesterday. The formula is:

```
=IF(J2="Done",IF(L2<>"",L2,NOW()),"")
```

I want to capture the time I finished a task in L2 when I choose "Done" from the dropdown list in J2.

This formula has been working well for the past few months but it suddenly stopped working and Excel has been prompting me this:
There are one or more circular references where a formula refers to its own cell either directly or indirectly. This might cause them to calculate incorrectly. Try removing or changing these references, or moving the formulas to different cells.

I recreated the problematic part of my tracker in a new Excel file and the problem still remains. So I think it is definitely the formula. Here is the [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/iqxhpwcsiow77k8orkq65/Sample.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=9x09tj8dhascc4qdqpd2knr6n).

Can someone please help me out? Many thanks to this awesome community!

Comment: Hi @Moon Tail,, better share the WB on cloud/Drop Box,, with us to examine and fix the issue!

Comment: Hi @RajeshS. Thank you for the reminder! I added a link to a sample tracker with the same problem. It would be great if you can help!

Comment: Hi @Moon Tail,, the problem is ITERATION,,, which U need to activate,,, since B2 is part of the formula now [Check this link I've modified the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/otfahi124cscc01/Sample.xlsx?dl=0) ,, read instructions also.

Comment: Hi @RajeshS. This solved my problem perfectly! Thank you so much! Have a great day and stay safe!

Comment: Glad to help you @MoonTail,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Formulas` tab, open `Error checking` dropdown list in `Formula auditing` group, go to `Circular references` - there you can see all cells addresses where are problems.

[image]

Comment: Hi @basic. I believe the formula I have used became incompatible with Excel. I recreated the problematic part of my tracker in a new worksheet and the error still exists. Here is the link to my sample file if you would like to take a look: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/iqxhpwcsiow77k8orkq65/Sample.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=9x09tj8dhascc4qdqpd2knr6n